# Spring : How to stop deployment on Tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web

I have a classic web application managed with Spring 3.1.1.
In my web.xml, i have a DispatcherServlet.
And i have some @Component with @Autowired public constructor.

I would like to stop the deployment of web application if any constructor throw an exception.
How to do that ?

Thank you.

---

Here an exemple:

```
@Autowired
public ConfigLoader(
        @Value("$BO/../XXX/XXX.XXX") final String propertiesFileName,
        final ResourcesLoader resources) {
    this.resources = resources;

    boolean error = false;
    try {

        try {
            }
        } finally {
        }
    } catch (final IOException io) {
        logger.error(resources.getProperty("config.loader.exception"));
        logger.error(resources.getProperty("application.stop"));
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(io);
    }

    if (error) {
        logger.error(resources.getProperty("config.loader.error"));
        logger.error(resources.getProperty("application.stop"));
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any exception occuring during bean initialization/startup of the `ApplicationContext` will result in failure to startup. If that isn't the case you have something wrong in your setup or are catching exceptions before Spring can react on them. Also you should be throwing an `Exception` not an `Error`. Something like `IllegalStateException` or the like and also provide a useful message, this makes debugging a lot easier.

Comment: Maybe i have a pb with setup. I had to put context-annotation-config, context-component-scan and mvc-annotation-driven in servlet.xml configuration. Without that RequestMapping in controller doesn't work. So i have no ApplicationContext.xml. Perhaps that's why Exception doesn't stop web application ?